# Move around a selection of edges without horizontal or vertical movement?

Tags: vertices

is there a way to move around a selection of vertices on the planes surface without moving it up or down?
I just want to quickly slide it around the plane

For example after cutting out a square in a plane i want to quickly select the edges of that square to move it around without up or down movement just snapped on the same level of the plane, esp when i just use G to move

Comment: Pressing G to move, then **Shift+Z** will allow you to move your selection on all axes _except for) the Z (moves on X and Y only).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett approach only works if the plane is perpendicular to an axis. If you want to move it on a plane that has been tilted you need to hit shif+Z twice before moving.